# Keras NLP Neural net predicting the next letter - ValueError: An operation has `None` for gradient

Tags: tensorflow, keras, nlp

Hello everyone I am running into the above error. I assume my it has to do with the shapes of my network or preprocessing of the target?

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

link = "https://en.wikisource.org/wiki/Moral_letters_to_Lucilius"
res  =requests.get(link)
res.status_code


soup= BeautifulSoup(res.text,'html5lib')


a  =soup.find_all('a')



alllinks = []
for h in a:
    try:
        link = h['href']
        alllinks.append(link)
    except:
        pass



x = [link for link in alllinks if "Letter" in link]


final = ['https://en.wikisource.org/'+p for p in x]


import re
def getletter(link):
    res = requests.get(link)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(res.text, 'html5lib')

text = '\n'.join([x.text for x in soup.find_all('p')])
text = re.sub("\s\s+ "," ",text)
text = re.sub("\[\d+\]",'',text)
text = re.sub('\d+.','',text)
text  = text.replace('\n\n',"\n")
return text


keys = [f"Letter {i}" for i in range(1,len(x)+1)]

values = [getletter(f"https://en.wikisource.org{z}") for z in x]


dic = {k:v for k,v in zip(keys,values)}

complete = "\n".join([val for val in dic.values()])


vocab = sorted(set(complete))

char2idx = {c:i for i,c in enumerate(vocab)}


# In[29]:


d2n = [char2idx[char] for char in complete]

import tensorflow as tf


def shift(seq):
    input_data, target_data = seq[:-1],seq[-1]
    return input_data,target_data

SEQ_LEN = 100
BATCH_SIZE =64
BUFFER = 10000

dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(d2n)

sequences = dataset.batch(SEQ_LEN+1, drop_remainder=True)

dataset = sequences.map(shift)

dataset = dataset.shuffle(BUFFER).batch(BATCH_SIZE,drop_remainder=True)

from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense,Embedding,Dropout

model = Sequential([
    Dense(128, activation='relu', input_dim=100),
    Embedding(len(vocab),256),
    Dense(128, activation='relu'),
    Dropout(0.3),
    Dense(64, activation='relu'),
    Dropout(0.5),
    Dense(len(vocab),activation='softmax')
])
model.summary()
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy',optimizer='adam',metrics=['accuracy'])



history = model.fit(dataset, epochs=3)
```

Here is the error
ValueError: An operation has `None` for gradient. Please make sure that all of your ops have a gradient defined (i.e. are differentiable). Common ops without gradient: K.argmax, K.round, K.eval.

Comment: try to put Embedding as the first layer of you model

Comment: Thanks Marco, I have tried that before and receive a shape issue 
InvalidArgumentError: Incompatible shapes: [64] vs. [64,100]
  [[{{node metrics_1/accuracy/Equal}}]] [Op:__inference_keras_scratch_graph_2501]

I used input_length 100 for the embedding

Comment: Correct... your network is bit weird... you have to flatten your dimension to reconduct on 2D

Comment: Hi Marco, that is what I do not understand. If I take 1 batch of my dataset I get a tensor of  shape=(64, 100) for x and of (64,) for y. So 64 times a 100 sequence. So why do I need to flatten ? And how do I do that?